How to get the token to be used later in API REST
I need to upload files in a server, that requires a login to get a token to be used when I upload.
To login, I adapted How do we use restful APIs from Excel macros (vba)?
Sub LOGIN()

    Dim Request As Object
    Dim authKey As String
    Dim stUrl As String
    Dim response As String
    Dim requestBody As String
    
    stUrl = "https://WEB/oauth/connect/token?grant_type=client_credentials"

    Set Request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    
    requestBody = "{ ""client_id"": ""USERNAME"", " & """client_secret"": ""PASSWORD""}"
        
    With Request
        .Open "POST", stUrl, False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json"
        .send (requestBody)
        response = .responseText
    End With

    MsgBox responseText

I need to know the token to upload the files, but responseText is blank. If I try to save it in an Excel cell, it is also blank.
In a CMD screen with
curl -X POST -H "client_id:USERNAME" -u USERNAME:PASSWORD "https://WEB/oauth/token" -d "grant_type=client_credentials"

I don't receive any error, but also not any information.
How can I get the token response and save it in a variable in VBA?
This is the web: https://api.valenciaportpcs.net/messaging/swagger/index.html

Try this;
......
....
    XMLHTTP.send body
    
    If XMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
        response = XMLHTTP.responseText
        
        Dim myToken As String
        myToken = Replace(Split(Split(response, ":")(1), ",")(0), """", "")
        
        MsgBox myToken
    Else
        MsgBox XMLHTTP.statusText
    End If


If anybody look for something similar, finally I have found a correct code:
Dim response As String

Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
ClientID = "T077_API"
ClientSecret = "X6FYN6"

XMLHTTP.Open "POST", "https://www.valenciaportpcs.net/oauth/connect/token"
XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
'XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer"
body = "&grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=" & ClientID & "&client_secret=" & ClientSecret & ""

XMLHTTP.send body

Debug.Print XMLHTTP.responseText

response = XMLHTTP.responseText

Range("M11") = response

In response I get the access token. Now I'm trying to save this token in any variable.
Thks!
